# Load function causes "synchronous call" warning in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am loading some HTML pages using the code below.

```
$("" + loadDivSelector).load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        $("" + loadDivSelector).html("Unable to load the page");
    }
});
```

As I understood, this `load` function is supposed to be asynchronous. But somehow, Chrome still gives me a warning saying "synchronous XHR requests are deprecated".

What am I missing here? Isn't this supposed to be an asynchronous call?

Comment: It is. Perhaps you have some Ajax settings earlier  - or you are using an older buggy jQuery

Comment: Thanks. I will check those links out.

Checked few of them. Seems to me that something is causing the call to become synchronous. Apart from dom ready, there is no other call that might be blocking.

Comment: Update: Checked and disabled "Browser link" as well. Funny thing I noticed is that warning is displayed only once.